# Is there a way to increase the performance of this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have this kind of model:

```
Customer  (1) .... (n)  Orders
```

I can find all the orders of one customer with a simple query like this:

```
select * from Orders o join Customer c on o.customer_id = c.id;
```

I have a requirement of finding all current (today) orders of all customers if they have one, presenting all the customers.

Eg. The result I am expecting is something like this:

```
Customer     OrderDate           OrderStatus
Customer 1   2/1/2015 12:00:00        active
Customer 2   2/1/2015 13:00:00        closed
Customer 3    null                    null
Customer 4    null                    null
```

And the tables should look like these:

```
Customers
Customer 1
Customer 2
Customer 3
Customer 4

Orders        timestamp     CustomerID
Active   1/1/2015  15:00:00   1
Closed   1/1/2015  08:00:00   1
Canceled 1/1/2015  09:00:00   1
Closed   2/1/2015  11:00:00   1
Active   2/1/2015  12:00:00   1  //This is the last one of "TODAY" C1
Active   3/1/2015  18:00:00   1 
Closed   2/1/2015  13:00:00   2  //This is the last one of "TODAY" C2
```

The query that is working is:

```
select o.status, o.date, c.name from (
     select c.*, (
          select o1.id from orders o1 
             where o1.id_customer = c.id and o1.date between '2/1/2015 00:00:00' and "2/1/2015 23:59:59" 
             order by o1.date desc limit 1) as o
     from cliente c
) c left join orders o on o.id = c.o;
```

The problem is that with a small number of orders and customer the query is taking several seconds to execute. I expect that the orders number will increase in the short term and the number of customers too.

Is there a way to make more efficient this query? I feel that I'm tackling the problem in the wrong way.

Side note: I can't modify the model, can't include new columns. My first solution was including the last order to the customer and setting it every time an order is created but sadly I can't change the database.

Regards and thanks in advance!

[EDIT]

Table definitions

```
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
    `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    `cabin` enum('CABIN_A','CABIN_B','CABIN_C','CABIN_D','CABIN_E') DEFAULT NULL,
    `addressId` char(36) NOT NULL,
    `phone` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `datetime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `number` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `unitId` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `number_UNIQUE` (`number`),
    KEY `addressId_idx` (`addressId`),
    KEY `fk_customer_unit_idx` (`unitId`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_unit` FOREIGN KEY (`unitId`) REFERENCES `unidad` (`unitId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_address_customer` FOREIGN KEY (`addressId`) REFERENCES `address` (`addressId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `orders` (
    `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
    `customerId` char(36) NOT NULL,
    `status` enum('ACTIVE','CLOSED','CANCELED') NOT NULL,
    `datetime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `comment` varchar(700) DEFAULT NULL,
    `programDate` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `cabin` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    `unitId` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
    KEY `fk_orders_unit_idx` (`unitId`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_orders` FOREIGN KEY (`customerId`) REFERENCES `customer` (`customerId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_unit` FOREIGN KEY (`unitId`) REFERENCES `unit` (`unitId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: what does `explain select...` says for the query ? Share that into the question.

Comment: Note that dates adhere to a specific format in sql

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Comment: Hello Andy, I just added the table definitions. Regards!

Answer (score 2):

A simple `LEFT JOIN` without a sub-query should speed things up:

```
select  o.status, o.date, c.name 
from Orders o 
join Customer c
    on o.customer_id = c.id
    AND o.orderDate = '2/1/2015'
```

I'm assuming, as per original question (from "The result I am expecting...") that you want a NULL return for any customer that doesn't have an order today.

I am a bit confused why the 2 'Closed' and 1 'Canceled' orders for customer #1 are not part of "The result I am expecting" since you don't require `orderStats = 'Active'` in your "query that is working"...  Obviously since you list the closed order for customer #2 it isn't actually a requirement that the orders be open - perhaps you want to elaborate on that point.

Comment: Thanks Peter, yes my question is incomplete, sorry it was 2am :) The field is not a date, is a timestamp. The requirement is bring All the customers with all the last orders in the day. (I can have stored orders in the future) I will edit the question. Sorry

Comment: By the way, your answer is not fully working because I get duplicated Customers if they have more than one order in the current day. I need a resultset with the same number of customers that I have in the table customer and with the last order of today or null if they don't have an order. Thanks!

Comment: Um, "not fully working" by the question you wrote last night or by the subsequently edited question? (Actually this part is still not so clear in your question.)

Comment: Is not working with the edited question. I didn't explained correctly the problem so mislead to an incorrect interpretation of the expected result. I need that if I have 10 customers in Customer table, I get 10 customers in the result set with the last order in the current day. Thats the tricky part of the problem, getting the last order of a customer in a given day in a efficient way. The query that I posted is working fine, the limit 1 is doing the trick but it takes too much time with a relative small number or customers and orders.

Comment: See if anything here helps: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a simpler solution, using a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT c.name AS Customer,
       o.date AS  OrderDate,
       o.status AS OrderStatus
FROM cliente c
LEFT JOIN orders o ON (o.id_customer = c.id AND o.date = '2/1/2015')
```

But I'm wondering **why** you want to select the only first line between these two:

```
Closed   2/1/2015  1
Active   2/1/2015  1
```

What is this id? Customer id? Order id? Not that clear...

Comment: Sorry, my question was incomplete. I need to Select the "LAST" order of every customer in the day. In one day I can have several orders, the customer request is bring only the last order of the day. Something messy is that I can have orders in the future if they are programmed.

Comment: I edited the question to include that info. I can't get it work still. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this page: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/

I think You can use the row number for each group. You must grupping by Customer, and the order is customer_id, status.
And after You have the row number, select just the number 1.